# Exercise in calculating MLE

Tags: probability

I have an exercise that I cannot solve

Exercise.*A discrete random variable $x$ can obtain the values $1,2,3$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,p_3$, all the probabilities are unknown, but we know that $p_3=2p_2$. There are 100 independent samples $\{x_1,..,x_{100}\} \in \{1,2,3\}$. Find a maximum-likelihood estimation for the model parameters.*

Solution:

$P(x=1)=p_1$ $P(x=2)=p_2$ $P(x=3)=2p_2$

$MLE=\prod_{i=1}^{100}P(x=x_i)$

But this all I know, how to proceed the solution?

Comment: You have only one missing parameter since there are two equations given for the $p_i$'s. Their sum is one, and $p_3=2p_2$.

Comment: Hint: the likelihood (not the MLE...) is $$(1-3p_2)^{N_1}p_2^{N_2}(2p_2)^{N_3}.$$

Comment: @Did, I still don't understand how to proceed from here, apparently the MLE is $p_2 = N_2/100$, $p_1=1-3p_2=N_1/100$, $p_3=2p_2=N_3/100$

Comment: This is not making sense, for example why do you write that $\hat p_3=2\hat p_2=N_3/100$ and at the same time that $\hat p_2=N_2/100$? What is $\hat p_2$ exactly if $N_3\ne2N_2$? Looks like somebody should check again how this whole MSE stuff works.